# LyX: Export Warning! about BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, lyx

I'm trying to export a LyX file to LaTeX format and getting the following warning.

> LyX: Export Warning! There are spaces in the paths of your BibTeX databases. BibTeX will be unable to find them.

Any suggestion to handle this warning. Thanks

Comment: The warning is pretty clear: you have a BibTeX (`.bib`) database file, and it is in a folder which has spaces in the name. LaTeX and BibTeX _really_ do not like spaces in names: do not use them!

Comment: @Joseph: After removing the spaces in the files and folders names, I did not have any Export Warning. But we I compiled the Tex file, I got the following warning        Warning: Citation 'cite1' on page 1 undefined on input line 3. Citation 'cite1' on page 1 is undefined.       Any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the bibliography file correctly identified in the Lyx document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is pretty clear: you have a BibTeX (`.bib`) database file, and it is in a folder which has spaces in the name. LaTeX and BibTeX really do not like spaces in names: do not use them! (Making my comment into an answer.)